# Android grade syntax and build tools compatibility issues

Tags: android, gradle

I didn’t work full-time with Android in the last couple of years, and now whenever I try to fork someone code on GitHub I get a lot of errors since android tools and Gradle syntax are changing frequently.

I wonder what is the best way to handle these changes, and be able to upgrade other GitHub projects and some of my old projects to work with the latest Android tools. Here are some of the things that I struggle with:

- I noticed some of the issues are related to changes in the Gradle syntax. How can I know what Gradle version the build.grade syntax was written with? and then how to upgrade it to the current version (is there a migration guide for Gradle versions?).
- Sometimes I get issues related to tools that are not compatible with others, how can I know which version are compatible with which? and whats the easy way to manage that? here are some of these tools:

  - Gradle
  - Android Plugin for Gradle
  - Build Tools
  - Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know what Gradle version the build.grade syntax was written with?

If the project contains a `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file, that is the version of Gradle that the developer of the project is using.

> is there a migration guide for Gradle versions?

I am not aware of much Gradle syntax that would have changed that would affect Android developers for garden-variety projects. Most of the changes are from the DSL added via the Gradle for Android plugin. You can find the version of the plugin that the project developer was using via the `classpath` statement in the project's top-level `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

The above snippet is requesting version 1.3.0 of the Gradle for Android plugin.

Migration documentation for the Gradle for Android plugin is minimal. What there is can be found up on http://tools.android.com.

> how can I know which version are compatible with which?

[Here is Google's statement on the issue](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility), though this has not been updated in a few months.

> and whats the easy way to manage that?

If the tools complain, change them to a set that you know is good (e.g., by copying values from a known-working project). If you need something that was introduced in a newer version of the tools, change them to a set that you know is good. Otherwise, don't worry about them.